# Stop Showing Breadcrumbs Instead of URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have a word press website, I have kept breadcrumb for each post. Now i want to show full URL in google SERP instead of showing breadcrumb.
But also i want to keep breadcrumb for internal linking and navigation purpose.

How do i show Full URL in google result keeping breadcrumb for navigation.

PS: I am not a tech geek.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove any structured data you have on the website like schema.org or RDFa.

If you have YOAST SEO plugin, you can disable this feature from it, sometime some themes have these options so you have to remove it from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Appearance>Customize>

Search there for breadcrumbs options for your Wordpress theme and disable it.